# Weird... iframe won't load unless it's interacted with?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I've written a HTML/CSS marquee that grabs some overlays from a site inside some iframes and then scrolls thru them. I'm getting some odd behavior from the page though.

When I first load the page and just watch it, only the first overlay shows. It scrolls in as expected, scrolls out, then nothing till the animation repeats - where the first overlay shows again.

When I interact with the page, each iframe loads as expected, in turn, with each scrolling in and out. (**intended behavior**)

If I interact, then stop interacting, the original problem comes back, but whichever iframe was last 'loaded' is the one that it repeats, instead of the first one.

"interacting" means having the page focused, with a mouse moving/clicking/hovering in the page somewhere.

Here's the code. Ignore the "display" statements in the animations, was trying to see if they would help show the iframes.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @keyframes mq1 {
            0%  { display: show; }
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            1%  { transform:translateX(0);      }
            9%  { transform:translateX(0);      }
            10% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            10% { display: hidden; }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq2 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            10%  { display: show; }
            10% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            11% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            19% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            20% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            20% { display: hidden; }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }

        }

        @keyframes mq3 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            20% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            21% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            29% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            30% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq4 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            30% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            31% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            39% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            40% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq5 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            40% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            41% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            49% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            50% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq6 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            50% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            51% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            59% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            60% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq7 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            60% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            61% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            69% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            70% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq8 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            70% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            71% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            79% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            80% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq9 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            80% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            81% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            89% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            90% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq10 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            90% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            91% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            99% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }
        .marquee {
            width: 300px;
            height: 150px;
            margin: 10px auto;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            white-space: nowrap;
            vertical-align: text-top;
            border: 2px;
            border-color: white;
        }

        .marquee iframe {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            text-align: center;
            transform:translateX(100%);
        }

        iframe.marquee:nth-child(1) {
            animation: mq1 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(2) {
            animation: mq2 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(3) {
            animation: mq3 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(4) {
            animation: mq4 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(5) {
            animation: mq5 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(6) {
            animation: mq6 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(7) {
            animation: mq7 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(8) {
            animation: mq8 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(9) {
            animation: mq9 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(10) {
            animation: mq10 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }

/*
        .marquee.iframe:nth-child(1) {
            animation: left-one 20s ease infinite;
        }
        .marquee.iframe:nth-child(2) {
            animation: left-two 20s ease infinite;
        }
*/
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="marquee">
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/347710c7-d003-47ec-8c56-29269060692c"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/687c5759-99f1-4f40-95c3-377cfb1751be"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/b8efb59c-02ae-4edf-9c9d-50a6d1643064"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/80fc2dab-f197-452e-827d-36aafdeca87d"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/76576b68-97aa-42a5-a5e4-45574ab0d3e9"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/fe174a33-4b60-4bcd-aed6-3188dbf1d432"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/7c1a3a59-7540-4c15-a5b4-24d19dbd5880"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/ebc95461-8851-4576-a8bf-0f8aec7c9d46"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src=""></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src=""></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i should specify - i need to be able to just let it run, without interaction - it's for a stream overlay.

Comment: did you tried adding allow="autoplay" atribute to iframe

Comment: <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/ebc95461-8851-4576-a8bf-0f8aec7c9d46" allow="autoplay></iframe>

Comment: I have not - i'll give that a try

Comment: I don’t think this is your problem, but display show and hidden are not CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the browser is being a bit to clever....

You have a translate(100%) on the iframes as well as overflow hidden on the parent.

If you remove either of these things work as expected. That is, the iframes start to show after an initial pause and move in and out of the visible parent OK.

With both of these set it is as if the system has said 'right, that iframe isn't visible so I wont get hold of it' and it doesn't 'realise' that the subsequent transform should make it visible.

Now, why should a mouse action on the page change this? I don't know because I don't know exactly how a browser would decide to do a repaint, but it does appear that that is what is happening. A mouse event triggers a reflow and at that point the system realises an iframe is on show and shows it. Hopefully someone who understands the inner workings of browsers can explain this better.

Anyway, a cure for your problem is to remove that transform: translateX(100%) from the iframes. The system then seems to realise that the iframe is viewable.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @keyframes mq1 {
            0%  { display: show; }
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            1%  { transform:translateX(0);      }
            9%  { transform:translateX(0);      }
            10% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            10% { display: hidden; }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq2 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            10%  { display: show; }
            10% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            11% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            19% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            20% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            20% { display: hidden; }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }

        }

        @keyframes mq3 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            20% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            21% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            29% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            30% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq4 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            30% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            31% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            39% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            40% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq5 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            40% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            41% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            49% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            50% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq6 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            50% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            51% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            59% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            60% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq7 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            60% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            61% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            69% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            70% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq8 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            70% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            71% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            79% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            80% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq9 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            80% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            81% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            89% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            90% { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }

        @keyframes mq10 {
            0%  { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            90% { transform:translateX(100%);   }
            91% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            99% { transform:translateX(0);      }
            100%    { transform:translateX(-100%);  }
        }
        .marquee {
            width: 300px;
            height: 150px;
            margin: 10px auto;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
            white-space: nowrap;
            vertical-align: text-top;
            border: 2px;
            border-color: white;
        }

        .marquee iframe {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            text-align: center;
            /* REMOVED transform:translateX(100%); */
        }

        iframe.marquee:nth-child(1) {
            animation: mq1 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(2) {
            animation: mq2 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(3) {
            animation: mq3 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(4) {
            animation: mq4 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(5) {
            animation: mq5 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(6) {
            animation: mq6 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(7) {
            animation: mq7 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(8) {
            animation: mq8 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(9) {
            animation: mq9 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }
        iframe.marquee:nth-child(10) {
            animation: mq10 80s ease 5s infinite;
        }

/*
        .marquee.iframe:nth-child(1) {
            animation: left-one 20s ease infinite;
        }
        .marquee.iframe:nth-child(2) {
            animation: left-two 20s ease infinite;
        }
*/
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="marquee">
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/347710c7-d003-47ec-8c56-29269060692c"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/687c5759-99f1-4f40-95c3-377cfb1751be"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/b8efb59c-02ae-4edf-9c9d-50a6d1643064"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/80fc2dab-f197-452e-827d-36aafdeca87d"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/76576b68-97aa-42a5-a5e4-45574ab0d3e9"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/fe174a33-4b60-4bcd-aed6-3188dbf1d432"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/7c1a3a59-7540-4c15-a5b4-24d19dbd5880"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src="https://tracker.gg/overlays/overlay/ebc95461-8851-4576-a8bf-0f8aec7c9d46"></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src=""></iframe>
        <iframe class="marquee" src=""></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was messing around with the translate myself and noticed that they show up in the vscode browser just fine this way, but it still wasn't showing up in my overlay in OBS. But, I removed the overflow:hidden as well and that worked, as long as the browser source was wide enough to show an edge of the iframes off to the side.